# Update and reposition object in array in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

```
const state = [
  {10: {a: 22, b: 33}},
  {12: {a: 20, b: 33}},
  {15: {a: 22, b: 34}},
  {5: {a: 21, b: 30}},
  {9: {a: 29, b: 33}},
]
```

State is an array of objects like above. When the app updates an object, the object should flow up to the first position.

E.g. let's say that we take the second object above (with the primary key `12`), and copy and update it so it looks like this:

```
{12: {a: 45, b: 33}}
```

And now we want to insert it to the array with the following result:

```
const state = [
  {12: {a: 45, b: 33}},
  {10: {a: 22, b: 33}},
  {15: {a: 22, b: 34}},
  {5: {a: 21, b: 30}},
  {9: {a: 29, b: 33}},
]
```

I understand how to update an object in an immutable fashion, but I cannot get my head around how to accomplish the above.

Comment: Updated answer below.  If that doesn't help, can you elaborate further as to what part of the process is stumping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
// an update function, here it just adds a new key
// to the object
const update = (x) => ({
  ...x,
  hello: "world"
});

// a filter factory
const withId = (id) => (item) => Boolean(item[id]); // item with specific ids
const withoutId = (id) => (item) => !Boolean(item[id]); // others

const state = [
  {10: {a: 22, b: 33}},
  {12: {a: 20, b: 33}},
  {15: {a: 22, b: 34}},
  {5: {a: 21, b: 30}},
  {9: {a: 29, b: 33}},
];

const id = 5;
const newState = state
  .filter(withId(id))
  .map(update)
  .concat(state.filter(withoutId(id)));


console.log(JSON.stringify(newState, null, 4));
```

What this does is filtering the state between the items you want to update and the rest, apply the update to the selection and concat the untouched items to them.

Below another example on with the same idea  which illustrates that you can perform the update on more than one item :

```
const markAsDone = (todo) => ({
  ...todo,
  done: true
});
const isInGroup = (group) => (todo) => todo.group === group;
const not = (predicate) => (x) => !predicate(x);

const isWork = isInGroup("work");
const notWork = not(isWork);

const state = [
  {
    todo: "go shopping",
    group: "life"
  },
  {
    todo: "go work",
    group: "work",
  },
  {
    todo: "go sleep",
    group: "life"
  }
];

// get work related todos, mark as done and 
// append to todo list
const newState = state
  .filter(notWork)
  .concat(state
    .filter(isWork)
    .map(markAsDone));


console.log(JSON.stringify(newState, null, 4));
```

Comment: Being a novice, does this modify state in an immutable way?

Comment: iep, the  update function creates a brand new object which merges the old one and add a new property, leaving the old one untouched, the `map` and `filter` and `concat` also create brand new arrays. The logic in this script is to filter out the desired items, update them in an immutable way and concat the results with the rest.

Comment: A very eloquent solution. The only missing piece is the non-dynamicness of the update function. But of course, that was not the center of the question.

Comment: You can easily add it. For instance with a toggle function : `const makeToggle = (field) => (todo) => ({ ...todo, [field]: !Boolean(todo[field]) })` which creates a toggle on a specified field. In the previous example you could have `toggleStatus = makeToggle("done")` . It's actually a pattern, you first filter your data, apply a transformation to a subset then merge it back.

Answer (score 1):

something like this perhaps?

```js
const state = [
  {10: {a: 22, b: 33}},
  {12: {a: 20, b: 33}},
  {15: {a: 22, b: 34}},
  {5: {a: 21, b: 30}},
  {9: {a: 29, b: 33}},
]


// find the numerical index of the object with the specified "key"
function findIndexOfKey(array, key){
  return array.findIndex(function(el){return key in el});
}


// modify object and move to front
function editObjectAndMoveToFront(array, key, updatedValues){
  // find index of object with key, for use in splicing
  var index = findIndexOfKey(array, key);

  // create the updated version of the specified object
  var originalObject = array[index];
  var originalObjectValue = originalObject[key];
  var editedObject = {};
  editedObject[key] =  Object.assign({}, originalObjectValue, updatedValues)

  // here is the new state, with the updated object at the front
  var newArray = [
    editedObject,
    ...array.slice(0, index),
    ...array.slice(index + 1)
  ]
  return newArray
}


const newState = editObjectAndMoveToFront(state, 12, {a: 45, b: 33})
console.log(newState);
```